# What DNS settings are related to proxying DNS using SOCKSv5 by means of an openssh tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, dns, proxy

USE CASE: I have a functional Debian Stretch machine. It has WAN access through my router with operational DNS resolving (I can ping www.google.com and get a response). It runs **open-sshd** which I use as a **SOCKS5 proxy**. For instance I use Putty on MS. Windows machines to **tunnel** their traffic through unprotected networks and/or overly protected networks (i.e. I use it as a poor-man's VPN). Normally, this setup worked perfectly.

PROBLEM: Now that I have a new router I run into the following issue:

Once I turn on "**Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5**" in the client that uses the proxy/tunnel (Firefox in this case) the **tunnel lags** immensely (talking minutes here) when I try to resolve for instance www.google.com. When I use Google's IPv4 instead (172.217.17.100) it is loaded nearly instantly.

So I already narrowed it down to a DNS (timeout?), but here my knowledge fails me Hence my question here:

- **What are the routing settings that may be related to DNS resolving when being proxied (especially in relation to the aforementioned use-case)?**

Nota bene 1) The machine running opensshd has no problems using DNS itself (it is as if it simply does not extend that functionality to the openssh tunneled client).

Nota bene 2) The issue is bigger than simply turning off the remote DNS usage in the client (possible in Firefox) as many programs always (not configurable) use the DNS from the server on the endpoint of the tunnel (mostly for privacy reasons).

P.S. May this post be related: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32188/what-is-ip-over-dns-tunnelling

Comment: Sorry I have not enough reputation to comment and ask you for more information. It seems that your primary DNS server on your client is unreachable from the Socks proxy (maybe a private, company internal). Can you change the DNS server on the client to a one that would be reachable from the proxy (maybe a public one) ?

Comment: Thank you @vera for responding! In the mean time I found the issue. Bud would I not have; than your reply should have surely get me on the right track too! In my case my primary DNS was pointing to a non excising [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/instance) instance (a DNS relaying service to filter adds from the network). My regular clients simply switched to the secondary (my router) as it does not exist anymore, but the ssh-tunneling proxy apparently did not (waited until time-out or something in that vein). Removing the referral to the non-existing Pi-hole DNS server removed the lag! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although many more settings are probably related to DNS-by-proxy, the one that was causing the lag in the described case was simply the primary DNS pointing to a non-excising one ([pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/instance) instance). It seems that regular clients simply switched to the secondary one (in this case the router) as I took the the Pi-hole one down some weeks ago, but the ssh-tunneling proxy apparently did not switch so easily (but instead waited minutes or even until a time-out or something along those lines). At any rate; removing the referral to the non-existing Pi-hole DNS server removed the lag!